# Can I remove break line (enter) in multi txt files?

Tags: text, line, break

I have a folder contains some .txt file. I wish to remove break line (enter) in each file. Is it possible to do?

Example for folder tree structure:

```
Action
   |--15minutes.txt
   |--2012.txt
   |--alien.txt
   |--alien3.txt
   |--......txt
Animation
   |--9.txt
   |--aladdin.txt
Family
   |--addamsfamilythe.txt
   |--big.txt
   |--t.t.txt
   |--happy.txt
   |--kungfupanda.txt
```

Example for txt file's contain:

```
ALADDIN:  THE COMPLETE SCRIPT

COMPILED BY BEN SCRIPPS 

(Portions Copyright (c) 1992 The Walt Disney Company

PEDDLER:    Oh I come from a land

    From a faraway place

    Where the caravan camels roam

    Where they cut off your ear /Where it's flat and immense

    If they don't like your face /And the heat is intense

    It's barbaric, but hey--it's home!

    When the wind's at your back

    And the sun's from the west
```

What I want to get:

```
ALADDIN:  THE COMPLETE SCRIPT COMPILED BY BEN SCRIPPS  (Portions Copyright (c) 1992 The Walt Disney Company PEDDLER:    Oh I come from a land     From a faraway place     Where the caravan camels roam     Where they cut off your ear /Where it's flat and immense     If they don't like your face /And the heat is intense     It's barbaric, but hey--it's home!     When the wind's at your back     And the sun's from the west
```

(in 1 line only)

Comment: Yes, but it depends on what OS you have.  Are you using linux, Windows, OS X, ... ?  What programming languages do you know?  If you are not a programmer, you might be able to find an existing application by asking at SuperUser.com  .  Read [tour] and [ask] to see what questions belong here.

Comment: I am using Linux, and Python also. I want to remove break line to make the text contain become 1 line only, but I spent much time to do one by one. Could you please suggest me some solutions?

Comment: or find + https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114244/replace-all-newlines-to-space-except-the-last

Comment: find + sed  can do it. Google for many example and tutorial pages besides the link above

Comment: find + sed seems to be work for me, but how can I write "Enter" character in command line?

Comment: try \r and \n  (return and newline)

Comment: I found a solution: ```find . -name "*.txt" -exec sed -i -e ':a' -e 'N' -e'$!ba' -e 's/\n//g' '{}' \; ``` Anyway thank you very much for your suggestion <3